# RoR User Access to more than 1 team

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for some advice before I start work on a bit of a hobby project. I am setting up an application for a couple of local sports groups I am involved in.

I want the majority of people to log in and see only the information about the teams they work with, however some people such as myself work with multiple teams and so when I log in I would like access to all of the info and jump between the teams I work with.

I am using Devise to control user log in.

Would it be better to use active record and filter each view to which ever team the user has access to or Nest Teams under users or am I missing an even better way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following models structure:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :team_memberships
end

class TeamMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In your case i would scope the teams to the current_user. ie:

For the /teams path (simplified example)

```
class TeamsController < ApplicatitonController
  def index
    @teams = current_user.teams
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, forgive my naivety as I am learning RoR to do this project, but how would that work and how would it limit the data?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how you could have structured your models